# Do in-kind security transfers from a US broker to another US broker keep track of the cost bases and holding periods?

Tags: united-states, taxes, transfer, cost-basis, securities

If the specific US brokers matter, securities would move from Fidelity to Charles Schwab.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible through the [DTCC's CBRS](https://www.dtcc.com/clearing-services/equities-clearing-services/cbrs) or manually. Whether your brokerages support that - you'll have to ask them. Most major brokerages should be able to support the automated reporting (especially if they already use the [ACATS](https://www.dtcc.com/clearing-services/equities-clearing-services/acats) for the account transfer itself).

Comment: If they don't support it for purchases after about 2011-2015 (depending on type) they're breaking the law. This requirement was enacted during the great recession in 2008/9, but implemented in phases presumably to reduce burden. I remember several years when my 1099 package included a long explanation about 'changes to basis [and term] reporting effective this year'. My brokers' webites, and _some_ of their statements, designate 'covered' and 'uncovered' (before 2011-ish) holdings.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that's right. I believe both CBRS and ACATS are legally (or, at least, regulatory) required, but I couldn't find any actual reference to any such law so I didn't put it in the answer.